# Concatenated String misses some symbols

Tags: php

I try to build a url string that includes the users email address, username and a hash value. To get those values and build the string I use the following code:

```
$name = $_REQUEST['username'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$hash = md5(rand(0, 5000));
$url = "https://website.net/path/file.php?username=" . $name . "&email=" . $email . "&hash=" . $hash;
```

My problem is that the hash is not represented in the form "hash=abcdefgh" (when the hash value would be "abcdefgh"). Instead it is represented as "hashdefgh". So the part "=abc" is missing for some reason.

I really can not find a reason why this happens.

It also happens when I do not use the "." for concatenation but build the string with help of the PHP's str_replace method.

Comment: No repro https://3v4l.org/rHfjY

Comment: Personally, I'd use [http_build_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/function.http-build-query.php) to build the query string... `$query = http_build_query(["username" => $name, "email" => $email, "hash" => $hash]);`

Comment: That the error couldn't be reproduced gave me an idea and I found out that it is the email provider that causes this error. I used trash-mail all the time and they remove those four symbols for some reason. I just tested it with freenet and the string was represented correctly. Do you have any idea why trash-mail does this and how I can avoid this error with other providers?

Comment: No idea. Raise an issue with the provider

Comment: I have tested your code and it works as expected.

Comment: _"Do you have any idea why trash-mail does this"_ - we have no information on how exactly you are sending this via email yet. Could be a matter of missing encoding.